# Translating equation to latex code

Tags: subequations, convert

```
\[
w\textsubscript{\lambda,\rho}(x\textsubscript{i}) 
= \dfrac{\lambda \left| \kappa x\textsubscript{i}\right| 
\textsuperscript{\rho}} {\sum_{k=1}^{\left|V\right|} 
\left|\kappa x\textsubscript{k}\right|\textsuperscript{\rho} 
v(x\textsubscript{k})} + \dfrac{(1 - \lambda) 
\left|\eta(x\textsubscript{i})\right| $\rho$}
{\sum_{k=1}^{\left|V\right|}\left|\eta (x\textsubscript{k})\right|
\textsuperscript{$\rho$} ν(x\textsubscript{k})}
\]
```

I am trying to write this equation in overleaf but the code doesn't work. What is wrong ? How can i fix it ?
[image]

Comment: Don't use `\textsubscript` and `\textsuperscript`. inside of math mode. Instead of `x\textsubscript{i}`, simply use `x_{x}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have a blank line in your math environment. You shouldn't, as blank lines denote the start of a new paragraph.  *Unrelated*: why do you use `align*` for a single line? ou don't have whatever to align. Simply use  `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: For starters, replace `w\textsubscript{\lambda,\rho}(x\textsubscript{i})` with `w_{\lambda,\rho}(x_{i})`.

Comment: Also, remove all occurences of `$` inside of your `align*` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to compose your source text for it to be easyly readable and checkable. The code is not only to be understood by the compiler, it must be quickly and easyly read by the human. Use comments and group your code by units of meaning.

\ textsubscript and \ textsuperscript are for text, not for mathematical expressions: use '_' and '^'

align * is a math environment, so '$' is not needed to display math symbols. $\rho$ must be typed \rho in an math environment

```
  \begin{align*}
    w_{\lambda,\rho}(x_{i})% Left member
    %
    =%
    %
    \frac{% First frac
    \lambda \left| \kappa x_{i}\right|^{\rho}}% Numerator first frac
    {\sum_{k=1}^{\left|V\right|} \left|\kappa x_{k}\right|^{\rho} v(x_{k})}% Denominator first frac
    %
    + %
    %
    \frac % Second frac
    {(1 - \lambda) \left|\eta(x_{i})\right| \rho}% Numerator second frac
    {\sum_{k=1}^{\left|V\right|}\left|\eta (x_{k})\right|^{\rho} \nu(x_{k})}% Denominator second frac
  \end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version of your equation. As Bernard already noted, an `align*` environment is not neccessary if you only want to show one equation. A simple `\[`, `\]` also works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
w_{\lambda,\rho}(x_{i}) = 
  \frac{\lambda \lvert \kappa x_{i} \rvert ^{\rho}} 
        {\sum_{k=1}^{\lvert V \rvert} \lvert \kappa x_{k} \rvert ^{\rho} v(x_{k})} + 
  \frac{(1 - \lambda) \lvert \eta(x_{i}) \rvert \rho}
        {\sum_{k=1}^{ \lvert V \rvert} \lvert \eta (x_{k}) \rvert ^{\rho} \nu(x_{k})} 
\end{align*}


\[
w_{\lambda,\rho}(x_{i}) = 
  \frac{\lambda \lvert \kappa x_{i} \rvert ^{\rho}} 
        {\sum_{k=1}^{\lvert V \rvert} \lvert \kappa x_{k} \rvert ^{\rho} v(x_{k})} + 
  \frac{(1 - \lambda) \lvert \eta(x_{i}) \rvert \rho}
        {\sum_{k=1}^{ \lvert V \rvert} \lvert \eta (x_{k}) \rvert ^{\rho} \nu(x_{k})} 
\]
\end{document}
```